# Fill a table top-bottom with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have an object at hands, containing an unknown number of properties. Each and every one of these properties, I want to represent as a list item in a `table` where the elements are spread out either equally top-to-bottom between the set number of columns as shown below or when they reach a maximum number.

**The dataset:**

```
{"one", "two", "three", "four"}
```

**The result I want:**

```
one   |  three |
two   |  four  |
      |        |
```

So how would I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Do you specifically want table markup, or are you just trying to organize columns?

Comment: Well, It's going to go in to html later, just put it here in text form to make it a bit clearer to understand

Comment: Are you wanting to stop at 3 going down?  Or some other arbitrary number?

Comment: It would just as good to have either a fixed number vertically or the elements  equally distributed

Comment: Is the dataset always an object of arrays? Will there be multiple arrays in the set?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Always an object with properties. No multiple arrays though

Comment: @Industrial I updated the answer and added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a table and a simple Javascript/jQuery solution.  you could do something simple like this.  Simply figure out your object length, divide by two, and build your table. See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aa9pK/)

Not professing this is some kind of magic, but a very basic way of accomplishing what you demonstrated in your question (if I understood correctly).  At the very least hopefully this gets you started.

JS:

```
var trCounter = 0;

var myObj = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];

var objHalf = Math.round(myObj.length / 2); // your example shows two columns

$(myObj).each(function(i) {

    if (i < objHalf) {
        // build initial table rows and first column
        $("#myObjOutput").append("<tr><td>" + myObj[i] + "</td></tr>");
    }
    else {
        // add subsequent column with remainder of data
        $("#myObjOutput tr:eq(" + trCounter + ")").append("<td>" + myObj[i] + "</td>");
        trCounter++;
    }

});
```

html:

```
<div>
    <table id="myObjOutput">
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myObjOutput td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `CSS3` you can set `column-count` attribute of your container:

```
#container {

    column-count: 2;
    column-rule: 1px solid #000;
    column-gap: 1em;
}​
```

and then increase `column-count` with `JQuery (JavaScipt)` when needed.

---

**Update**

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/haEfQ/) demo.

Comment: Thanks for this clean solution. Unfortunately I have to stay away from the CSS3 goodies so I had to select  Betards answer...

Comment: I look forward to when CSS3 and HTML5 are the mainstream as @fardjad's answer is quite elegant and simple.  Unfortunately with so many browsers out there that either have no support (I'm looking at you IE6) and then mixed support across newer browsers, it will be a quite awhile before we wont have to worry about compatibility for such a large percent of users.